# Can't clear inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

I'm doing practical Javascript course on watchandcode.com and my code is exactly the same as the instructor's, but the part where it clears the inputs does not work here.

```
changeTodo: function () {
    var changeTodoPositionInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoPositionInput').valueAsNumber;
    var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoTextInput').value;

    todoList.changeTodo(changeTodoPositionInput, changeTodoTextInput);

    // THIS PART DOESN'T WORK
    changeTodoPositionInput.value = '';
    changeTodoTextInput.value = '';
}
```

The function does its job, it's just those last two lines that don't work.

Comment: Because `changeTodoPositionInput` and `changeTodoTextInput` are values and no DOM elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to clear a value and not input elements, you have to get the DOM elements first :

```
var changeTodoPositionInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoPositionInput');
var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoTextInput');
```

Then get the value after that from them :

```
todoList.changeTodo(changeTodoPositionInput.valueAsNumber, changeTodoTextInput.value);
```

And now you could clear the value of the both inputs using :

```
changeTodoPositionInput.value = '';
changeTodoTextInput.value = '';
```

**FULL CODE :**

```
changeTodo: function() {
    var changeTodoPositionInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoPositionInput');
    var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoTextInput');

    todoList.changeTodo(changeTodoPositionInput.valueAsNumber, changeTodoTextInput.value);

    changeTodoPositionInput.value = '';
    changeTodoTextInput.value = ''; 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

var changeTodoPositionInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoPositionInput').value = "";

var changeTodoTextInput = document.getElementById('changeTodoTextInput').value = "";